# OOZIE - E0803: IO error

Tags: oozie, hortonworks-data-platform

Iam trying to execute under an Hortonworks distribution the map-reduce oozie example... 
but it's functional yet...

First, here my Custom Hadoop Configs (from Ambari). I had to modify the core xml to correct my "impersonate" problem...

```
hadoop.proxyuser.oozie.groups=*
hadoop.proxyuser.oozie.hosts=*
```

Work well, but now i have this :

```
Error: E0803 : E0803: IO error, <openjpa-2.1.0-r422266:1071316 fatal store error> 

org.apache.openjpa.persistence.RollbackException: The transaction has been rolled back. 
See the nested exceptions for details on the errors that occurred. FailedObject: org.apache.oozie.WorkflowJobBean@3f623c47
```

I already found persons with the same error but no solution... May be can you help me!

My job.properties (on local)

```
nameNode=hdfs://namenode01:8020
jobTracker=namenode01:8021
queueName=default
examplesRoot=examples

oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/oozie/${examplesRoot}/apps/map-reduce
outputDir=map-reduce
```

and my workflow.xml (on HDFS)

```
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.2" name="map-reduce-wf">
    <start to="mr-node"/>
    <action name="mr-node">
        <map-reduce>
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <prepare>
                <delete path="${nameNode}/oozie/examples/output-data/${outputDir}"/>
            </prepare>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                    <value>${queueName}</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.mapper.class</name>
                    <value>org.apache.oozie.example.SampleMapper</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.reducer.class</name>
                    <value>org.apache.oozie.example.SampleReducer</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.map.tasks</name>
                    <value>1</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.input.dir</name>
                    <value>/oozie/examples/input-data/text</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.output.dir</name>
                    <value>/oozie/examples/output-data/${outputDir}</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
        </map-reduce>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="fail"/>
    </action>
    <kill name="fail">
        <message>Map/Reduce failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

Iam trying to execute my wf with :

```
oozie job -oozie http://edgenode01:11000/oozie -config /home/oozie/examples/apps/no-op/job.properties -run
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi, have you solved this one?

Answer (score 0):

Open Job History at your-hadoop-host:50030/jobhistory.jsp and find your job. There go to map tasks and see logs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using derby db - check the db location to see if there are any lock files which owned by user other than intended - if yes remove it and stop and start oozie again.